# Want a dynamic size ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I want an `ImageView` that sets its height to `340dp` and width to `wrap_content` when the height is bigger than the width, and when the width is bigger than the height it sets its height to `wrap_content` and its width to `400dp`.

And I want to implement all of that with keeping the aspect ratio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set your `ImageView`'s layout size by specifying
   `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.
2. To keep the aspect ratio of your image loaded into the inside of the layout bounds of your `ImageView`, you can set `android:scaleType` to `fitCenter`.

So, your `ImageView` in `layout.xml` can be defined like blow:

```
<ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        (...)
        />
```